# ClosedXML Adding Data to Existing Table

Tags: c#, openxml, closedxml

With ClosedXML I am trying to add data to an existing Excel Sheet In an Existing Table. The easy thing to do is to add a table to an excel sheet below is a quick example of how to do that. What I don't understand is if you already have a Table there that is empty how can you just add to the existing table?

```
// Add a DataTable as a worksheet
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dataTable);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question... what do you call an "empty table" in Excel... (almost) everything is table in Excel. Could you put a screenshot, it would be lot more understandable

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how this question isn't clear to people.  If there is an existing Table (created in Excel by going to "Insert -> Table") and you open an Excel document using ClosedXML, adding data to the next row does not automatically expand the Table.

You can expand it prior to adding the data as such:

```
IXLTables tsTables = thisSheet.Tables;
IXLTable firstTable = tsTables.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstTable != null)
    firstTable.InsertRowsBelow(1);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Glad you came along and posted an answer almost a year after this was asked, as years later its still helpful :)

Comment: yep, I had to come back here to find it again almost 4 years after I solved this problem the first time.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar requirement, where I needed to insert data into an existing Table, which had a number of data validations / comments / formula built in.

I found that the easiest solution (for me) was to use the Table's *ReplaceData* call.  This is particularly useful if you provide a name for your Table in the Excel worksheet, as that way you can get a reference to the table directly from the workbook, ie:

```
var candidateTable = workbook.Table("Candidates");  
candidateTable.ReplaceData(candidateData, propagateExtraColumns: true);
```

Note that the key to getting this to work properly is to set the *propogateExtraColumns* parameter - this will ensure any formula / etc you have set will automatically be copied to any new rows that are created.

FYI - you can set the Excel Table's name by selecting your table in the worksheet, clicking the Design tab, and then entering a table name:

[image: Enter table name in Excel]

Answer (score 3):

To add a `DataTable` to an existing worksheet use this:

```
wb.Worksheet(1).Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(dataTable);
```

More info in the [documentation](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-Tables).

Comment: Yes this is a way to add a new table to the existing work sheet. My issue is being able to populate the existing table on that work sheet with the data. Every time I replace it or add a new table to the work sheet it messes up the formulas. So far I did get it to work by removing the entire worksheet, creating a new worksheet adding a new table and than naming the worksheet and table. As you can imaging that is a lot of extra coding that shouldn't have to be done to achieve this task. though